# Reading a file without mentioning its specific file name in R

Tags: r, file, path, read.table

I have some files (.tst) in a folder called datasets. The file names of these files are relatively long (time stamps etc) and named automatically after running some codes. It means the file name I want to read is changing every time I run the codes.

Is there a way to read a file without giving the specific file name? For example, my files name are W.2021-10-15.12345678901.tst and M.2021-10-15.123456789.tst. I want to read the file with W.

I have tried reading it by giving the absolute path such as

```
read.table(file = '/home/myname/project/datasets/W*.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
```

but it failed and reported "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection". Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a better approach would be to read all file names in the directory, find the match, and then read that complete name.

```
tmp=list.files()
tmp=tmp[grep("^W",tmp)]
read.table(tmp,...)
```

You better pray that there is only 1 match.

Comment: Yes it is indeed ony one file since I programmed to remove the file for the next running commands. The output is showing a file name, but as the character tho. So read.table(tmp, ) means reading a character and it's wrong, right? I'll try to find a way to change this character class to a file itself.

Comment: @MKHuda tmp should store the string which matches the pattern, which is what you pass to read.table, the name of the file.

Comment: what is the argument (...) after tmp in read.table(tmp, ...)? Yes, tmp results the complete file name, but when I tried to read read.table(tmp) or read.table(tmp, path to the file) it is error showing the "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection". Any idea?

Comment: @MKHuda if your environment is not currently located where the file is located then you have to provide the full path to the file. Which means that you probably have to merge two strings to get the full path and pass that to read.table.

Answer (score 2):

```
# list all tsv files that start with "w"
filenames <- list.files(pattern="^w.*?\\.tsv")

# read them all at once into a list called "file_list"
file_list <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {read.table(x, sep = "\t", header = T)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Resolve in the names of the files: 
# file_paths => character vector
file_paths <- list.files(
  path = "~/project/datasets",
  pattern = "^W.*\\.tsv$",
  full.names = TRUE
)

# Allocate some memory: df_list => empty list: 
df_list <- vector(
  "list", 
  length(file_paths)
)

# Read the tables into a list: df_list => list of data.frames
df_list <- lapply(
 file_paths,
 function(x){
   read.table(
     x, 
     sep = '\t', 
     header = TRUE
     )
   )
 } 
)

# If you can combine them (i.e. all columns are present in 
# the .tsv in the same order): df => data.frame
df <- do.call(
  rbind,
  df_list
)
```